# Undefined nextElementSibling of an element's parent

Tags: jquery

I have a collapsing menu I want to control with a separate  tag. I think my issue is that the menu that collapses/expands is separated from the button that triggers the change.

The structure is like so:

```
<div>
  <p>blah blah</p>
  <a class="collapsible">click here to collapse/expand</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading"></div>
```

The key here is that the menu that collapses/expands is separated from the button that trigger the change.

My JQuery looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");

    for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = $(this).parent().nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.maxHeight){
          content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } 
        else {
          content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

When I click the  tag however, I get the error "Cannot read property 'maxHeight' of undefined."

Why is the element undefined as opposed to finding the sibling panel-heading? Is there a different way to reference the object?

Thank you for any help or insight

Comment: You are mixing plain JavaScript properties with jQuery methods.

Comment: @zer00ne I was under the impression that both were accessible to me. If there's a purely JS or purely JQuery solution that would be ideal, but I guess I'm missing the knowledge to fill those in.

Comment: Review my answer as I ramble on incoherently :p Let me know if I don't make any sense. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Objects do not recognize most plain JavaScript methods and neither does Plain JavaScript Objects know what jQuery methods and properties are. So when using properties such as `nextElementSibling` you need to dereference the jQuery Object back to a Plain JavaScript Object. Dereferencing jQuery objects come in 2 flavors:

**Minty Zero-index in Bracket Notation**

```
  $(jQObject)[0]
```

**Zesty jQuery `get()` Method Passing Zero Index**

```
  $(jQObject).get(0)
```

### Demo

```js
$('.collapsible').on('click', expandCollapse);

function expandCollapse(e) {
  var uncle = $(this)[0].parentElement.nextElementSibling;
  $(uncle).slideToggle('fast');
}
```

```css
.panel-heading {display:none}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>blah blah</p>
  <a  href='#/' class="collapsible">click here to collapse/expand</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>



<div>
  <p>blah blah</p>
  <a href='#/' class="collapsible">click here to collapse/expand</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>



<div>
  <p>blah blah</p>
  <a href='#/'class="collapsible">click here to collapse/expand</a>
</div>

<div class="panel-heading">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>









<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `$(jQObject)[0]` is slightly confusing.  First off, if all you are going to do after making a jQuery object is break the raw dom element out of the object, then don't turn it into a jQuery object in the first place.  You are performing an unnecessary step.  Secondly, your pseudocode variable name `jQObject` could be interpreted as already being a jQuery object, in which case sticking it inside `$()` is pointless.  It's already a jQuery object.

Comment: Like I said incoherent rambling (see comment above), I'm pressed for time, but if you have the time I don't mind if you edit it

Comment: This makes perfect sense. So when dealing with the JQ element, I should reference the parent with the parentElement property, and using vanilla .parent() is what threw my undefined error. Thanks :)

Comment: `parent()` is **not** vanilla javascript.  It is jQuery.

Comment: @Taplar concerning the first 2 examples, I used the variable name to reinforce the fact that `$(X)` is a jQuery Object. Since variable names can be arbitrary and this is a standalone example with no references to previous code or a coding style pattern established, I think it'll be ok. The dereferencing in the Demo was not done out of necessity, it was done to demonstrate dereferencing. I am stronger in JavaScript than I am at jQuery so I find myself switching back and forth often, but it allows me to take advantage of both and my code is terse and still readable (if you know `$(X)[0]` means)

Comment: @Ryan you are correct, sir, except as Mr. Taplar explained, `parent()` is a jQuery method. If you placed a period after "vanilla", you be correct (yet grammatically awkward).  But I knew what you meant to say ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var content = $(this).parent().nextElementSibling;
```

`nextElementSibling` is a raw DOM Element property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).  jQuery does not directly expose most Element properties with its interface.  Rather, you have to go about this in one of a few ways.

## You could break the object out of jQuery

```
var content = $(this).parent()[0].nextElementSibling;
//or
var content = $(this).parent().get(0).nextElementSibling;
```

Both of these will return the DOM Element, which you can access the property directly off of.

## You could use the `prop()` method

```
var content = $(this).parent().prop('nextElementSibling');
```

`prop()` will return the DOM Element property you give it the name of.

## You could use the `next()` method

```
var content = $(this).parent().next()[0];
```

`next()` returns the next sibling to the element, which from the documentation appears to be what `nextElementSibling` references.